# ProtonVPN broke my machine after upgrade to Linux CLI version 3

Tags: networking, vpn

I'm using the ProtonVPN Linux CLI client Ubuntu 18.04.

I was previously using the 2.2.6 version, but I wanted to upgrade, which was a huge mistake.

I uninstalled v2.2.6 and followed the instructions for installing v3.7.1 on the ProtonVPN website.

After installation, I was able to create a connection, use the Internet, etc. Everything seemed to work. I enabled the killswitch permanently with `$ protonvpn-cli ks --permanent`.

Then, I closed my laptop lid. When I re-opened it, I had no Internet connection. I expected this, since that's how the 2.2.6 client worked, and I'm used to having to manually reconnect every time I open my laptop.

I attempted to reconnect to the VPN, but it didn't work the way I expected. `$ protonvpn-cli r` wouldn't find previous connection data, and `$ protonvpn-cli c` returned the error

```
Setting up ProtonVPN

An unknown error has occured.  Please ensure that you have internet connectivity.
If the issue persists, please contact support
```

My wifi connection was fine. If connectivity is the issue, then I assume it must be the killswitch. I disabled the killswitch with `$ protonvpn-cli ks --off`. My first question is, under v.2.2.6 I did not have to disable the killswitch in order to connect to ProtonVPN itself. Is this changed in v3.7.1?

With the killswitch disabled, `$ protonvpn-cli r` continues to not find previous connection data, but `$ protonvpn-cli c` at least makes an attempt at working. However, it's still broken. It takes a minute to load the list of countries. When I select "United States", it seems to freeze while loading the list of servers. I've tried several times, and I've reconnected my wifi. It just won't load servers.

My device now lacks internet connectivity entirely.  I've turned off the killswitch, I've closed the terminal I was running `protonvpn-cli` in, and there are no `protonvpn` processes active on the machine.  The wifi is fine, and other devices are using it to connect to the Internet perfectly well.  I've even rebooted the laptop, but it still won't connect to the internet.  ProtonVPN has completely wrecked it.

Please help me.

Answer (score 7):

Although I don't think the problem still persists on your side I've struggled with similar problem today. For me the solution found here https://askubuntu.com/questions/1319033/internet-stops-working-after-installing-protonvpn solved all connectivity issues, by simply removing the ***pvpn-ipv6leak-protection*** as following:

```
sudo nmcli connection delete pvpn-ipv6leak-protection
```

Comment: This solved the new problem created by protonvpn, AS WELL AS the original issue of my internet being inexplicably slow. Why? I'd like to know!

Comment: Well I assume the reason therefor can be found in the explanation of this connection:

"ProtonVPN applications block all IPv6 traffic by default. [...] any potential IPv6 traffic is routed to a black hole (null route) to ensure your device cannot make connections over IPv6. [...] Also, by disabling IPv6 traffic on your network, your internet connection performance shouldn’t be affected[...]." 

But I've often experience having IPv4 + IPv6 enable the same time impacts network in a negative way. So disabling IPv6 instead of routing it to a null route is better approach.

Answer (score 2):

This is from proton's own old web page on how to remove the leftover "always on kill switch" uning command lines in the terminal.  It is on the page: "How to install early-access Proton VPN Linux CLI"
located @ https://protonvpn.com/support/linux-vpn-tool-early-access/

3. Disable the kill switch if you have uninstalled the app

The kill switch can be easily disabled from within the official Linux CLI app, but this will not be possible if you have uninstalled the CLI app first without disabling the kill switch. This may result in your system being unable to access the internet. To remove the kill switch after the CLI app has been uninstalled:

a) Identify Proton VPN connection names by running the command:

nmcli connection show --active

This will display a list of all your system’s active connections.

b) Look for any connections with the pvpn- prefix. This usually includes pvpn-killswitch and pvpn-ipv6leak-protection, and may include pvpn-routed-killswitch. Delete all these connections using the following command:

nmcli connection delete [connection name]

For example:

nmcli connection delete pvpn-killswitch

c) Re-run the following command to verify that Proton VPN connections have been deleted:

nmcli connection show --active

If any Proton VPN connections remain, delete them as described above.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know enough about linux to be helpful but have run into the same issue.

Seems to be that proton stuffs with the resolv.conf file.

This link has a fix https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/cpzaxo/remove_protonvpn_from_ubuntu/

But I can't get it to work as chattr will not allow me to remove the -i permissions.

chattr: Inappropriate ioctl for device while reading flags

Maybe it will work for you